# Check if any vi process is editing a file, or swapfile exists?

Tags: invocation, swap-file, viminfo

I'm writing a script to ensure that everything I work on on my system is committed, pushed to Git etc. I'd also like to check if there are any vim swapfiles active (either in a running Vim, or from abnormal exit).

How can I check? Short of starting a vim for each tracked file and somehow checking if vim complains about recovery / swap active.

Even nicer would be to check *from the outside* if there are modified buffers in any running vim instance, but that doesn't seem too feasible

**NOTE** I'm keeping all my swapfiles in a separate dir (`:set directory=`), so it's hard to associate swaps with reals (probably requires parsing `viminfo`)

Comment: What about setting [`:h 'directory'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27directory%27) to something like `~/.vim/swap/` and then checking for the existence of files in this directory (`ls`, `find`, or whatever you are comfortable with)?

Comment: I already have it set to ~/.vim/bakfiles (used for all undo, baks, swp's etc), but there are many inactive swapfiles left over even when no vim running

Comment: Ah my bad, I use `noswapfiles` and I was sure that vim deletes the swapfile when it's done with a buffer.

Comment: It might delete swaps by default, I don't remember -- mine is heavily customized over a long time

Comment: Swapfiles are supposed to disappear when vim exits correctly. It might be worth using a double-/ in directory, though, as that gets you full file-path information.